# Where can I learn more about tapping on an acoustic guitar?

Tags: technique, learning, guitar-tapping

I want to learn tapping on acoustic guitar; its basics, various techniques and so on. How should I start with it? Reference of some video lessons would be a great help.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to start with tap harmonics. It's quite easy and sound really great on acoustic. Check out this video lesson: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhOzgDwMHQg 
(skip ahead to about 5:30).

Answer (score 2):

Go check out some artists like Andy McKee and his song [Drifting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ddn4MGaS3N4). It's a lot easier than it looks when you're trying to learn it because it kind of repeats the same thing for the beginning but with little changes. One thing, though, is that the guitar is tuned to DADGAD.

Comment: I have been listening, rather watching Andy Mckee for long. But I could not dare to play looking at the way he plays! Possibly, I should practise much harder to get this clean :)

Comment: Perhaps you'd like this question then: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/what-are-some-good-slap-guitar-resources

Comment: Andy McKee is awesome, but watching an expert is not a good way to learn for a beginner.